# Make nested directory structure recursively

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

How do I create a set of nested directories using Python where The depth of nesting can vary and needs to be handled by the program. For example, in the future the user may add one or more subdirectories under the 'Raw' directory.

Further to this - each directory created may or may not have a list of files that the program will be required to copy in to the directory. I was thinking nested dictionaries for all of the dictionaries, then finally a list containing strings paths to the source files.

So far I have:

```py
import os

# Create destination directory struictyrwe

path = './test'
directories = {
    'Block_models': {},
    'Borehole_data': {},
    'Design_data': {},
    'Grid_models': {'Assay': ['Raw', 'Wash'], 'Structure': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']},
    'Map_files': {'Assay': [], 'Structure': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']},
    'Spec_files': {},
    'Triangulations': {'Faults': [], 'Structure': [], 'Topography': []}}


for k, v in directories.items():
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, k))
        if v:
            for l, m in v.items():
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, k, l))
                if m:
                    for n in m:
                        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, k, l, n))

    except FileExistsError as e:
        print(f'One or more directories already exist {e}')
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

- I think you need use `os.makedirs` to create intermediate folders.
- You can use `recursion` to deal with nested directories with vary depth.

#### code:

```
import os
path = './test'
directories = {
    'Block_models': {},
    'Borehole_data': {},
    'Design_data': {},
    'Grid_models': {'Assay': ['Raw', 'Wash'], 'Structure': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']},
    'Map_files': {'Assay': [], 'Structure': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']},
    'Spec_files': {},
    'Triangulations': {'Faults': [], 'Structure': [], 'Topography': []}}

def recursion(path,dic):
    try:
        for k,v in dic.items():
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, k))
            if v:
                recursion(os.path.join(path, k),v)
    except AttributeError as e:
        for ele in dic:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, ele))
    except FileExistsError as e:
        print(f'One or more directories already exist {e}')

recursion(path,directories)
```